# jquery loop through each textarea and copy to corresponding span class

Tags: jquery, loops, printing, each

I have several forms that need to be printer friendly. I am trying to come up with the simplest way to loop through each textarea, grab the value and place it into a span tag that is below it with the class name "forprint". So far I have only figured out how to copy the value into the container but am unable to figure out how to copy each of them to the corresponding container. Please help! Here's an example of what I am doing right now:

```
<div class="fullWidth">
    <span class="label">Personalized Menus: </span><span class="forscreen">@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.PersonalizedMenues, AdminOnlyAttribute(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "k-textbox" }, { "rows", "4" } }))</span>
    <span class="forprint"></span>
    <br /><br />
</div>

<div class="fullWidth">
    <span class="label">Food Labels: </span><span class="forscreen">@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.FoodLabels, AdminOnlyAttribute(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "k-textbox" }, { "rows", "4" } }))</span>
    <span class="forprint"></span>
    <br /><br />
</div>

<div class="fullWidth">
    <span class="label">Table/Seating Signs: </span><span class="forscreen">@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.TableSigns, AdminOnlyAttribute(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "k-textbox" }, { "rows", "4" } }))</span>
    <span class="forprint"></span>
        <br /><br />
</div>

<script>
    $('textarea').blur(function () {
        var copyText = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
        $(".forprint").html(copyText);
    });
</script>

<style>
.forprint {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    .forprint {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }

    .forscreen {
        display: none;
    }
}
</style>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Also its worth noting that not all of the textareas on each form are in order like this so I can't just grab all of them and put them in one container.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML and not whatever language `@Html.TextAreaFor` is.

Comment: The rendered html is just a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the parent and then get the forprint inside of that.

```
$('textarea').blur(function () {
    var copyText = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'),
        parent = $(this).parents(".fullWidth");
    $(parent).find(".forprint").html(copyText);
});
```

Here is a working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/weEX8/